# node load multiple order by

Tags: nodes

How can I order by weight using node_lode_multiple and the weight module ?

```
   <div id="photos_inner">
         <?php 
           $type = "staff";
           $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
           foreach($nodes as $staff):
         ?>
```

Comment: You need to give us more information in order to help you.

Answer (score 2):

No, results of `node_load_multiple()` are in the order in which the node IDs were passed to it in the first place. There are no other sorting options through that function.

The weight module doesn't appear to have an API for this, so you'll need to create a query that joins the `node` and `weight_weights` tables to get the nids in the right order, *then* pass them to `node_load_multiple()`.

Comment: node_load_multiple() return an array of node objects indexed by nid.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Clive's answer, you can do it this way:

```
$type = 'your_content_type';
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('weight_weights', 'w', 'n.nid = w.entity_id');
$query->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('type', $type)
  ->orderBy('w.weight', 'ASC');
$nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Comment: I have checked this but it seems it return an array of node objects indexed by nid. The same is also mentioned on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7.x